# 'levels' function in R returning incorrect results

Tags: r, csv, levels

I have a data table in R containing a number of groups with multiple readouts for each of them, like so:

[image: Example Data Table]

So each sample (e.g.'7001') has an age (15), and there are multiple images of each sample that form the rows of the table, each with a result associated with them.

The table is quite large, and i think there may be a problem with the 'structure' of it, because I am getting anomalous results from the 'levels' function.

Doing the following:

```
  levels(Sample_No.)
```

returns the correct result (`[1]` "7001"   "7002"   "7003"   "7004"...). However if I try to subset the data, e.g. by age:

```
levels(Sample_No.[Age=="15"])
```

I still get the same readout, and not just the Sample numbers that are aged 15. 
To look into this further I just took the first and last few values of my table (which was originally 6000 rows) to create a new table, like so:

```
newlist = rbind(head(oldlist), tail(oldlist))
```

This list is only 12 rows and definitely only contains two Sample Numbers (say "7001" and "7200") yet when I run `levels(newlist$Sample_No.) I get the same readout as before  (`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q6fG.png)` "7001"   "7002"   "7003"   "7004"... "7200").

This suggests to me that it's not simply a problem of a few misplaced age values, but a problem with the table or the commands I'm using to subset.

Thanks in advance for help.

Additional info:
Table dimensions: 6116 by 15.
File format is .csv, read using the `read.csv` command with all defaults `(Header = TRUE)` etc

Comment: As @rawr stated, levels in a `factor` vector are preserved when subsetting. Try this: `x<-factor(letters); levels(x[1])`.

Comment: @rawr I think you put `droplevels` and `levels` in the wrong order. Shouldn't it be `levels(droplevels(Sample_No.[Age=="15"]))`?